# What's the best way to implement the file format of a dictionary application?

Tags: performance, file, dictionary, format

I want to write a dictionary application on the android platform. Now I have some basic idea of how to organize the dictionary entries in a file. I want to hear from you guys opinion on what's the best way to organize the entries in a file in order to get best performance.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, there are already perfect systems for storing, searching and retrieving data. They are called databases.

It looks like the nice in process database [SQLite](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) exists for Android.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Trie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) =)